# Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input 1: OffenceAgainst ~ ^

Tags: r, list, loops, parsing, tidyverse

I am trying to loop over a list of character vectors and use other functions to form linear models and calculate values for me:

```
all_model_error<-function(explan_vars,depvar,dataset1,dataset2)
{
 x<-list() 
 model_combinations<-all_models(explan_vars)
  for(i in 1:length(model_combinations))
  {

    x[[i]]<-error_rates(model_combinations[[i]],depvar,dataset1,dataset2)


  }
 return(x)

}
```

However when I run this function I get this error in parse. `parse()` is not used in any function within this function, and I am confused as to why I am receiving this error.

The underlying functions are defined as such:

```
gen_formula<-function(depvar,explan_vars)
{

  reg_form<-as.formula(paste(depvar,"~",paste(explan_vars,collapse = "+")))

  return(reg_form)

}
```

This just returns your input in a form that the lm() function takes.Then:

```
error_rates<-function(indvars,explan_vars,dataset1,dataset2)
{
  reg_results<-lm(gen_formula(depvar,explan_vars),data=dataset1)
  summary(reg_results)

  df_training<-dataset1 %>%
    add_residuals(reg_results) %>%
    summarize(error_rate=mean(resid^2))
  training_error<-df_training[1,1]

  df_test<-dataset2 %>%
    add_residuals(reg_results) %>%
    summarize(error_rate=mean(resid^2))
  test_error<-df_test[1,1]


  return(c(test_error,training_error))

}
```

this just calculates the error of the model against your test and training data.
then:

```
name_from_bin<-function(b,vars)
{
  return(vars[as.logical(b)])
}



all_models<-function(variables)
{

  k<-length(variables)

  bin_vec<-rep(list(0:1),k)

  bin_mat<-expand.grid(bin_vec)

  list_of_RHS<-list()

  for(i in 1:nrow(bin_mat))
  {
    list_of_RHS[[i]]<-name_from_bin(bin_mat[i,],variables)



  }
  return(list_of_RHS)
}
```

These functions are used to create a matrix of all possible combinations of the number of variables on which to base a model. Then it returns these character vectors as a list, of every possible combination of variables.

I want to run all_model_error to find the error_rates() of all_models(). The underlying functions perform the task I want them to, and dont incude parse() which is why I'm confused with the error.

I am running all_model_error(explan_vars,depvar,crime_weather_1,crime_weather_2) and getting this error.
Where depvar is a single variable `OffenseAgainst` in my dataset, and explan_vars is a vector of 14 variables in the dataset. Crime_weather_1 and 2 are training and test datasets.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Probably one of `explan_vars` is invalid name i.e. contains space hence `as.formula` will fail.